# Can't run Pygame script that plays a OGG file compiled through cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, cx-freeze, python-3.3

When I compile the following script:

```
# play.py

import os, re
import pygame.mixer

pygame.mixer.init(11025)
pygame.mixer.music.load('song.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

os.system("PAUSE")
```

Using the following *setup.py*:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
exe = Executable(
script="play.py",
)

setup(
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

Through:

```
python setup.py build
```

Executing *play.exe* gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 2
7, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "play.py", line 7, in <module>
pygame.error: Couldn't open 'song.ogg'
```

The script works fine before compiling and yes, I did put *song.ogg* in *exe*'s directory. By the way *song.ogg* works fine, I already checked. Any ideas?

P.S. If I change it to *song.wav* it works fine, but WAV files are way too large for me to use. Also MP3 doesn't work as it should.

Comment: It probably needs some plugin to read ogg files, and that isn't being copied across to the exe directory. If it's a Python module, you can tell cx_Freeze that it needs to include it ([docs](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html)). If it's a DLL, you can specify it as a file to copy.

Comment: I already tried that, searching in the Internet suggests I should copy libvorbis.dll to exe's directory, which sadly doesn't seem to work. I already tried contacting people that had the same issue and they said they weren't able to find a solution and had to switch to another language (like LUA). This is a awkward issue, pygame is supposed to support OGG by itself, even if I `import pygame` it won't work.

Comment: Switching to a whole different language seems like overkill. There must be a way to fix this, but I'm afraid I don't know what it is. Try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what extra DLLs get loaded when your (unfrozen) program loads an ogg file.

Comment: Through Process Explorer I was able to find out I needed to copy _libogg.dll_, libvorbis.dll and libvorbisfile.dll from Python33\Lib\site-packages\pygame to my frozen program's directory. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Since you've found the solution yourself, do you want to write it up as an answer and accept it, so that the question appears as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) I was able to find out I needed to copy *libogg.dll*, *libvorbis.dll* and *libvorbisfile.dll* from *Python33\Lib\site-packages\pygame* to my frozen program's directory.

Answer (score 0):

The computer cant open the song.ogg file because cx_freeze did not include the song in it's compiling. You should try including the song file into the `setup.py` script. Using a `setup.py` script like the one below.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

exe=Executable(
     script="play.py",
     base="Win32Gui",
     )
includefiles=[song.ogg]
includes=[]
excludes=[]
packages=[]
setup(

     version = "0.0",
     description = "Description",
     author = "Name",
     name = "Play",
     options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
     executables = [exe]
     )
```

Comment: Actually I already put the sound file in the frozen program's directory, I said that on the question. Anyway the problem is already solved.

Answer (score -2):

Expanding on your answer, I found the this solution for mac users (assuming you used [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install pygame):

```
    brew install libogg
    brew install libvorbis
    brew install sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis
```

If you receive a message saying "Warning: sol_mixer-1.2.12 already installed." after running the 3rd command, then replace it with the following:

```
    brew reinstall sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis
```

For reference: [can't open sound files using pygame on a mac](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/4267j7/cant_open_sound_files_using_pygame_on_a_mac/)