# Why am I getting this Pygame Music Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('audio/zombie_theme.ogg')
pygame.error: Unrecognized music format
```

there is the error. As you can see I am using an ogg file. Here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys, Funk
from tileC import Tile
from object_classes import *
from interaction import interaction
from A_Star import A_Star

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load('audio/zombie_theme.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is the file definately an OGG Vorbis sound file, and not some other file type, pretending to be an ogg by adding a .ogg extension? Can you check the magic byres in the ogg file header? Ref http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg the first 4 bytes of the file should be ASCII "OggS". Also see this question for a possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755921/cant-run-pygame-script-that-plays-a-ogg-file-compiled-through-cx-freeze

Answer (score -1):

Try with this if you want the background to infinite loop:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('audio/zombie_theme.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
```

Or this if you want it to play only one time:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('audio/zombie_theme.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

(I'm still new to python so i don't know if this will work for you, for me it work)

Oh yeah, and have you tried to set up a window? because i think it can't really work if you don't set up a window.

Comment: The first two bits in this answer don't relate to the original problem and the error message that was posted so aren't relevant (and really just repeat some the code from the question). The last point about having a window is really a question so should have been in the comment section. However, I'm pretty sure you don't need a window if you're just using the mixer (I'm pretty sure the full code will have a window anyway). Don't be put off by this comment, maybe you just need a bit more experience before posting answers.